# How do I add a custom msbuild project to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I want to add a custom MSBuild project file to my solution.  I have looked and there is the ability to add a .msbuildproj to the solution, but everytime I try to do it, it hangs Visual Studio.

What I am trying to do is add a project file that I can run MSBuild tasks as part of the overall solution build process.

**EDIT**

I am not looking to extend the existing build process.  I want to add a new project to solution that is not a csharp or cpp project.

Comment: "MSBuild.exe recognizes any project file name extension matching the pattern .*proj. However, Visual Studio only recognizes a subset of these project file name extensions, which determine the language-specific project system that will load the project. Visual Studio does not have a language-neutral MSBuild based project system." [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Create a .targets file called the same thing as your solution. Add your custom task(s) to run during a build into that new .targets file, and then insert something like this into each .*proj file included in your solution:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName).targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName).targets')" />
```

Be sure to inject this line just above the line in the file (near the end of the file) that reads:

```
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to execute the project independently.  I already use extension functionality in Microsoft.Common.targets to add both solution level and project level custom tasks.  What I need is the ability to have a standalone project in visual studio that I can "build" on its own.

Comment: Create an empty project and add it to the solution. Put your targets into that single empty project's vcxproj file.